# Question about acceleration

Tags: calculus

On this homework problem I'm pretty sure I know how to do it, but the answer choice is not there...

> The velocity of a particle is given by the equation 
>   $v(t)=2t^3 - 12t^2 + 12t +5$ over the interval $0\leq t\leq 3$. What is the smallest acceleration of the particle over this interval?

**A.** $5$

**B.** $0$

**C.** $-3$

**D.** $-12$

**E.** $-24$

I differentiated the velocity and plugged in values for $t = 0,1,2,3$ and got $12, -6, -12, -6$ but there is no $-6$ in the choices. Am I doing this wrong??

Derivative:

$a(t) = 6t^2 - 24t + 12$

Comment: It would help to provide the derivative that you calculated.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that we won't always be able to minimize a function over an interval just by plugging in a few values. In particular, the interval $0\le t\le 3$ also includes $t=0.1,$ $t=\frac\pi2,$ and many many many more values.

Now, there are two possible interpretations of "smallest acceleration" (as far as I can see). It could simply mean the minimum value taken on by the function $v'(t)$ over the interval. In that case, note that $-6$ is *not* the smallest acceleration value you've calculated, so it certainly isn't the smallest acceleration value over the interval. (As it happens, you already *have* found the minimum acceleration value over the interval, but you may need to justify why it is.)

The other possible interpretation is the minimum value taken on by $|v'(t)|$ over the interval. If *that* is what's intended, then you *haven't* yet found the smallest acceleration, and the point I made at the beginning becomes *very* important. To see what the true value should be under this interpretation, note that $v'(0)$ is positive and $v'(1)$ is negative. Thus, for some $0<t<1,$ we should have that $v'(t)$ is...what?

Comment: why is it not -6?? isnt that the least acceleration? -12 would mean its slowing down faster but has a larger deceleration

Comment: I have expanded my answer to address that interpretation, as well.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is take the derivative of the acceleration equation.

${\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}x}}6t^2-24t+12 => 12t-24$

To minimize set $12t-24=0$
,Then $t=2$.
Plug 2 back into the acceleration equation $6(2)^2-24(2)+12=-12$

The believe you messed up at two points:

-The question ask for the minimum value of the acceleration, when asked to find a minimum or maximum you want to take the derivative of that thing being optimized. Thats why the acceleration need to be differentiated

-You just plugged in natural numbers which fell in between the intervals, this happened to work in this case (you plugged in 2), but questions can  be set up such that the number which must be plugged in is a non natural number, and sometimes irrational.

Note: By looking at the graph of $6t^2-24t+12$ one can conclude that the minimum value will be around 2 (in this case exactly 2).

Comment: Also the question should be clarified, because deceleration can be counted as acceleration, in which case the smallest amount of acceleration is 0...(look at johannesvalks answer, or Cameron Buie second part of his/her answer)

Answer (score 0):

Well $-12$ is smaller as $-6$.

But when you consider smallest as closest to zero - then realize that between $t=0$ and $t=1$ there is a time for which the acceleration is $0$... That is for $t=2-\sqrt{t}$.